# Display Waveshare doesn't echo anything to the screen

Tags: screen, iot, sensors, android-things

I purchased a 5inch touchscreen WaveShark.

[Screen model](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD_(H))

I connected it to the board Raspberry Pi3 model B (OS Android Things) and it immediately displayed the contents of the program.

After that, I decided to go into the screen settings with the help of hardware keys.

As a result, the screen goes out and does not detract from the contents of the programs. Simply black screen without backlight.

Can I reset the screen to factory settings? Or how can I solve this problem differently?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: reflash the OS image

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't help

Comment: Try to connect your display to PC (via HDMI) and restore settings manually. And make sure, that settings fo display: [`hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1`](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD_(H)#Working_with_Raspberry_Pi): is in your `config.txt` file.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I get restore setting using PC?

Comment: Probably you can see display menu.

Comment: No, I don't see the menu :(

Comment: In that case, seems your display was broken.